# Regex for selecting substrings before and after a string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I am trying to find a right regex expression to select substrings between another substring, which I'd like to exclude. For example in this string:

```
11 - 12£ in $ + 13
```

I want to select `12£` and `$`. Basically, it's substrings around `in`,  until I hit an array of values I want to use as end/start, in this case, arithmetic operators `%w(+ - / *)`

So far closest I got was using this regex `/(.\d\p{Sc})\sin\s(\p{Sc})/`

Some more examples:

`10 - 12$ in £ - 13$` should return `12$` and `£`

`12 $ in £` should return `12$` and `£`

`100£in$` should return `100£` and `$`

Comment: You will have to post process these matches anyway since you can't skip a part of a match. Easiest is to use `(\d[\d\s]*\p{Sc})\sin\s(\p{Sc})` and remove whitespace from Group 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sentence.match(/[^-+*\/]*in[^-+*\/]*/).to_s.strip.split(/ *in */)
```

- `[^-+*\/]*` matches multiple non-arithmetic operators
- this will hence get everything from the *"opening"* to the *"closing"* operator that surround an `in`
- `#strip` removes the leading and trailing whitespaces
- finally, split into two strings, removing `in` and the spaces around it

Comment: This seem to work, but only going for one match. If I have `12£ in $ - 4$ in £` it'll only return first pair

Comment: @MaximFedotov use `scan` and `map` instead.

Comment: @MaximFedotov - You can do that with a scan: `sentence.scan(/[^-+*\/]*in[^-+*\/]*/).map { |el| el.to_s.strip.split(/ *in */) }`

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    \s+[+*\/-]\s+ # match 1+ whitespaces, 1 char in char class, 1+ whitespaces
    (\S+)         # match 1+ non-whitespaces in capture group 1
    \s+in\s+      # match 1+ whitespaces, 'in', 1+ whitespaces
    (\S+)         # match 1+ non-whitespaces in capture group 2
    \s+[+*\/-]\s  # match 1+ whitespaces, 1 char in char class, 1+ whitespaces
    /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = '11 -     12£ in $ + 13 / 13F in   % * 4'
str.scan(r)
  #=> [["12£", "$"], ["13F", "%"]]
```

See the doc for [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-scan) to see how `scan` handles capture groups.

Note that `'-'` must be first or last in the character class `[+*\/-]`.